# How would I go about checking if the user clicked on a square generated by fillRect & perform an action when they do so?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, graphics2d, mouselistener

I am coding a game in Java about dodging orange-ish red squares and clicking on them to delete them. However I need to figure out how I would code something to perform an action when a `fillRect` is clicked in the first place, if this isn't possible is there at least a way to figure out where a use clicked or check if they clicked in a certain area in general?

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { System.out.println(e.getXOnScreen()); }
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { }
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { } 
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { }
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { }
```

Comment: Use a mouse listener, and check if rectangle.contains(mouse position) when the mouse is clicked

Comment: This feels very vague and complex to me though, what I am currently attempting to do is this line of code, which isn't printing anything to console:

Comment: `public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
  System.out.println(e.getXOnScreen());
 }
 public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
 }
 public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
 }
 public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
 }
 public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
 }`

Comment: Your println doesn't appear to be inside of a method.

Comment: what do you mean? it's inside of `public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {`.

Comment: ok so this isn't really getting answered so i just wont implement it into my game until I become smarter about how to code these types of things in java /:

Answer (score 1):

ClickCanvas.java

```
public final class ClickCanvas extends Canvas
{
 private final List<Rectangle> squares=new ArrayList();

 ClickCanvas()
 {
  addMouseListener(new OnClick());

  for(int x=5;x<=305;x+=150)//3 by 3 grid of squares to click
  {
   squares.add(new Rectangle(x,5,50,50));
   squares.add(new Rectangle(x,155,50,50));
   squares.add(new Rectangle(x,305,50,50));
  }
 }

 @Override
 public void paint(Graphics g) //Painting Your Squares Here Called By Swing
 {
  super.paint(g);

  Dimension size=getSize();

  g.setColor(Color.WHITE);

  g.fillRect(0,0,size.width,size.height);

  g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);

  squares.forEach(square->g.fillRect(square.x,square.y,square.width,square.height));
 }

 private class OnClick extends MouseAdapter
 {
  @Override
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent m)
  {
   squares.removeIf(square->square.contains(m.getPoint()));//You do Your Action Here in this case i remove the square if it contains the mouse point

   repaint(); //Repaint The Canvas To Now Redraw Remaining Squares

   if(squares.isEmpty())
   {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Congrats You Win");

    System.exit(0);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

MainClass

```
public class ClickTest 
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
  JFrame frame=new JFrame("Click Test");

  frame.add(new ClickCanvas());

  frame.setSize(400,450);

  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  frame.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

I hope it gives you some insight on what you want to do in your game